Tailwind CSS throws error: 'Module not found: Can't resolve './${generatedImage}''
I am using NextJS and Tailwind CSS. Previously, I had this code (note: generatedImage is a url of an image):
<div
        ref={innerref}
        className={`${
            generatedImage ? `bg-[url(${generatedImage})]` : "projects-bg"
        } w-screen h-screen bg-cover mt-0 flex flex-col items-center`}
    >

After, I realised that you can't put variables inside tailwind classes, due to it throwing 
so I changed it to the code below:
<div
        ref={innerref}
        className={`${
            !generatedImage && "projects-bg"
        } w-screen h-screen bg-cover mt-0 flex flex-col items-center`}
        style={{
            backgroundImage: generatedImage && `url(${generatedImage})`,
        }}
    >

global.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

...bunch of css

However, it still throws the same error, even after resetting the stream (yarn dev). How do I make the error go away, and is the second piece of code valid? I think it is caused by tailwind, due to the error going away after removing @tailwind utilities, along with all the tailwind styles.

The second piece of code should be valid. Consider restarting the build system rather than resetting the stream.

how do you do that
